# Electrolysing two salts with the same anion

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

Assume that I prepare solutions of sodium chloride (NaCl) and potassium chloride (KCl) in equal molarity, then combine them together to form a single homogeneous mixture. Then I electrolyse this mixture.

While the reaction at anode would be simple enough:

$$\rm Cl^- \rightarrow Cl + e^-$$

What would be the reaction at the cathode? Would both potassium and sodium ions be converted into their neutral elements (and thence into their hydroxides) in equal amounts or would one of the cations be converted disproportionately more than the other? That is to say, would all potassium be first converted into its hydroxide before sodium and then sodium ions will start electrolysing or will there be an equal (by molarity) concentration of both the hydroxides from the very start?

Many thanks.

Comment: None of potassium nor sodium ions are reduced to the element. H3O+  and H2O are reduced to H2 and H2O or OH-. Potassium and sodium ions are just bystanders there.

Comment: @Poutnik that's a shortcut version of what really happens. The alkali metal cation is reduced to its elemental form, but being extremely reactive, they react with water to generate OH ions and hydrogen. But it's just splitting hairs, really. The question is, what would happen once the solute is evaporated? If half of the chloride ions have been oxidised to elemental chlorine, would those half stick predominantly with potassium or be distributed equally between potassium and sodium?

Comment: No, alkali metal ions are not reduced. such a reduction is the shortcut, simple but misleading version. When evaporated, there would be mixture of NaCl, KCl, NaOH, KOH, NaClO3, KClO3.

Comment: @Poutnik ok. The primary question remains.

Comment: There is no difference, compared to involving just one of the salts.  The result is mix of results for singular salts.

Comment: The more interesting question, with fewer distractions due to what happens to water, would be what happens if you electrolyse a mixture of *just* sodium and potassium chloride as a molten salt.

Comment: In case of molten salts and some solid-state reference electrode, the current as the function of the cathode potential would manifest two steps, probably partially overlapped, resembling common polarographic or voltammetric curves. The first one very probably for sodium ions.

Answer (score 1):

When electrolysing solutions of mixed alkali metal chlorides  $\ce{MCl}$, where $\ce{M=Na or K}$, the result is more or less the linear combination of results with pure salts, with deviation due different salt solubilities.

These processes occur:

**On the cathode:**

$$\ce{2 H3O+(aq) + 2 e- -> H2(g) + 2 H2O(l)}$$
$$\ce{2 H2O(l) + 2 e- -> H2(g) + 2 OH-(aq)}$$

$\ce{OH-}$ anion then electromigrate to the anode.

The former reaction is dominant in acidic pH, the latter one at alkalic pH.

**On the (inert, like glassy carbon) anode:**

$$\ce{2 Cl-(aq) -> Cl2(aq,g) + 2 e-}$$
$$\ce{Cl2(aq) + 2 OH-(aq) -> H2O(l) + Cl-(aq) + ClO-(aq)}$$
$$\ce{3 ClO-(aq) -> 2 Cl-(aq) + ClO3-(aq)}$$

**The net result:**

There are present ions $\ce{M+(aq)}$, $\ce{H3O+(aq)}$,$\ce{Cl-(aq)}$, $\ce{ClO-(aq)}$, $\ce{ClO3-(aq)}$, $\ce{OH-(aq)}$.
During evaporation, $\ce{H3O+(aq)}$ recombines with excess of  $\ce{OH-(aq)}$ and hypochlorite  decomposes to chloride and chlorate.

The solid rest after evaporation consists of $\ce{MCl}$, $\ce{MOH}$ and $\ce{MClO3}$.

Due relatively low solubility of $\ce{KClO3}$, chlorate salts will be enriched by potassium in expense of its context in hydroxide and chloride fraction.